# SQL Server Management Studio - Results to Text still outputs to Window

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I have a stored procedures that I am running. It generates print statements as a log of what is occurring along the way. By the end of it there would be about 14-15 million statements.

I chose send results to text file, but the messages are still being sent to the messages window. This concerns me as I am afraid that SSMS will run out of memory. Is there a way to disable sending the messages to the message window but still send them to a file?

I understand that I can log these messages to a table. I am looking for a solution in modifying SSMS behavior rather than changing the stored procedure.

Comment: If you selected 'Results to text' as the default destination for results, it only changes how the results are displayed in the Results window. How are you going to analyze 14-15 million statements?

Comment: If you selected 'Resuls to file' while your query window was open, try closing your query window and opening a new one. Then, when you execute the query, you should get a prompt of a file to save results to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way around this without doing something differently.

Output from SQL statements are written to a different buffer than informational statements like those from `PRINT`. `PRINT` output (and other messages sent to this buffer) isn't redirected to a file when you select "results to file", but is instead directed to the "messages" pane in SSMS. (The same thing happens when you use "results to grid".)

One way to get your log statements to go to a file rather than to the SSMS messages pane would be to convert your `PRINT` statements to `SELECT` statements - they would then be directed to the query results buffer and output to a file.

Another alternative would be to run your script with [`SQLCMD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) rather than with SSMS, and direct all the output to a file:

```
SQLCMD -i "your script file name" ~servername/authentication parameters~ > C:\logfile.txt
```

This would capture all the output from both buffers to the text file.

Comment: Thanks, I just want to give this a try before I mark it as the answer.  Hopefully by tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you that works with -i.  -q just hangs there for some reason FYI

Comment: Sorry just one thing to add, the option -r1 redirects all output to the stdout window.